# HTML5 + CSS3 Drop down Navigation Bar

Tags: html, css, hover, navigationbar

Everyone, I'm still a beginner at HTML5 and CSS3

I'm having a problem with the navigation bar which causes the bottom paragraph to move slightly when I hover. Any idea how to solve it or what's happening?

Here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>HTML5, CSS3 and jQuery Navigation menu</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nav.css">
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>

<body class="no-js">
  <nav id="topNav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" title="Nav Link 1">HOME</a></li>
           <li><a href="#" title="Nav Link 1">SERVICES</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Sub Nav Link 1">Sub Nav Link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Sub Nav Link 2">Sub Nav Link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Sub Nav Link 3">Sub Nav Link 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="Sub Nav Link 4">Sub Nav Link 4</a></li>
                    <li class="last"><a href="#" title="Sub Nav Link 5">Sub Nav Link 5</a></li>
                </ul>        
              </li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Nav Link 1">ABOUT US</a></li>
            <li class="last"><a href="#" title="Nav Link 1">ENQUITIES</a></li>
        </ul>
  </nav>      
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."<p>
  <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the CSS

```
/* JS disabled styles */
.no-js nav li:hover ul { display:block; }

/* base nav styles */
nav {
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  font: 16px Tahoma, Sans-serif;
}
nav ul { padding:0; margin:0; }
nav li { position:relative; float:left; list-style-type:none; }
nav ul:after { content:"."; display:block; height:0; clear:both; visibility:hidden; }

nav ul a:hover { color: #F90; border-bottom: thin; border-bottom-style:solid;}

nav li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: #333;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 600;
}
nav li a:focus { outline:none; text-decoration:underline; }
nav li:first-child a { border-left:none; }
nav li.last a { border-right:none; }
nav a span { display:block; float:right; margin-left:5px; }
nav ul ul { display:none; width:110%; position:absolute; left:0; background:#FFFFFF; }
nav ul ul li { float:none; }
nav ul ul a { padding:5px 10px; border-left:none; border-right:none; font-size:14px; }
nav ul ul a:hover { color: #F90; }

/* CSS3 */

.cssgradients nav li:hover { background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(0% 100px 90deg, #999, #222); background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#222), to(#555)); }
.borderradius nav ul ul { -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:4px; -moz-border-radius-bottomright:4px; -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:4px; -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:4px; border-bottom-left-radius:4px; border-bottom-right-radius:4px; }
.boxshadow.rgba nav ul ul { background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.8); -moz-box-shadow:2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8); -webkit-box-shadow:2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8); box-shadow:2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.8); }
.rgba nav ul ul li { border-left:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1); border-right:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1); }
.rgba nav ul ul a:hover { background-color:rgba(85,85,85,.9); }
.borderradius.rgba nav ul ul li.last { border-left:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1); border-bottom:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.1); -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:4px; -moz-border-radius-bottomright:4px; -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:4px; -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:4px; border-bottom-left-radius:4px; border-bottom-right-radius:4px; }
.csstransforms ul a span { -moz-transform:rotate(-180deg);-webkit-transform:rotate(-180deg); }
```

Actually, I'm doing this using a tutorial on it and trying to convert my own idea.
Anyone, please. Thanks.

Comment: Your borders are messing with stuff. Instead of not having borders on pieces, set them to 1px sold transparent.

Comment: @Torr3nt O.. Thanks =D I found the solution now ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're adding a 1px border to the bottom of a nav item when you hover over it. You're doing this on this line:

```
nav ul a:hover { color: #F90; border-bottom: thin; border-bottom-style:solid;}
```

Before hovering, none of the nav items have borders. Upon hovering, a border is created which moves the paragraph down 1px (the size of the border). Thus, you could set a `border-bottom` for all the nav items. If you don't want that border to show you can use `border-color: transparent`.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following line of CSS:

```
nav ul a { 
   border-bottom: thin; border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: transparent;
}
```